# How can I change the aspect ratio of images in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

(I am very new to php, so please forgive my blatant ignorance.)

My portfolio site theme uses this array to display realted images. Currently the theme crops those images to squares.  'images_proportion'  => 'marceau_core_image_size_square',

I would like to be able to control the size and proportions of these. Any thoughts on how I might do this would be greatly apreciated.

```
<div id="qodef-portfolio-single-related-items">
    <h4 class="qodef-m-title"><?php echo esc_html__('Related projects', 'marceau-core') ?></h4>
    <?php
    $params = apply_filters(
        'marceau_core_filter_portfolio_single_related_posts_params',
        array(
            'custom_class'                  => 'qodef--no-bottom-space',
            'columns'                       => '4',
            'posts_per_page'                => 4,
            'additional_params'             => 'id',
            'post_ids'                      => $related_posts['items'],
            'layout'                        => 'info-on-hover',
            'hover_animation_info-on-hover' => 'roll-out',
            'title_tag'                     => 'h5',
            'behavior'                      => 'columns',
            'images_proportion'             => 'marceau_core_image_size_square',
            'image_source'                  => 'featured',
        )
    );

    echo MarceauCore_Portfolio_List_Shortcode::call_shortcode( $params );
    ?>
</div>
```

I tried replaceing 'marceau_core_image_size_square' with actual ratios, like '16:9'. And I tried adding height and width to the array, but these megar efforts had no effect.

Comment: `(I am very new to php, so please forgive my blatant ignorance.)` ... please avoid self-shaming as it is not relevant to the clarity of your question [Should the string 'noob' be added to the blacklist for question titles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422604/2943403)

Comment: Is this WordPress question off-topic for [wordpress.se]?